# Creating global variable in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing a feature to track packages. So every time I create a new package I assign it a barcode_number. That is the global variable I would create. Every time I assigned that to a new package, I would increment it by one, thus ensuring that two packages would never have the same number.

Comment: Is this an X-Y problem? Are you sure that you need a global variable in the first place? You might be better served by describing what you're really trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern comes to mind:

```
class Permanent
  def self.increment
    @@val ||= 0
    @@val += 1
  end
  def self.value
    @@val ||= 0
  end
end
```

Invoke as `Permanent.increment` (or `Permanent.value` to just read the current value).  Obviously you can rename the class and methods to be handier.  You can make the starting value different than zero (or read it from a database or otherwise calculate it).   The main point is that the class would behave as a singleton for your purposes.

Comment: @MPorto If that is the case, it may be a good idea to either accept this answer, or respond with your own solution and accept that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found for this problem was that every time I need to assign a barcode number to a new package, I just look at the most recently added package, retrieve its barcode number, add one to that and assign this new number to the new package. It looks something like this:

```
barcode = ButtonFinishDiv.last.barcode + 1
ButtonFinishDiv.create(..., barcode: barcode)
```

Comment: Let's just hope no-one ever changes the default scope ordering...  Also, have a read-up on "race conditions".